# Setting defaults for my model fields like current time for 'created' and visits to zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a simple model that contains the follow fields: url, datecreated, lastaccessed and visited.

I have a form that provides the URL. Everything else I'd like to set manually. At the moment i've updated the create method in the controller to read:

```
@link = Link.new(params[:link], created: Time.now, lastaccessed: Time.now, visited: 0)
```

That didn't work. I'm not sure how to input fields into a model that haven't come from the form. Is this also the right way? Should i maybe write this in the model instead of the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge all your params into one hash like so:

```
@link = Link.new(params[:link].merge({created: Time.now, lastaccessed: Time.now, visited: 0}))
```